# Hide input but still let JS auto fill data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a set of 3 input fields, that take the first and second input and do some math to auto fill the third input.

I don't want the third input to be seen, but using `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` both return `NaN` in out database. Is there anyways to just hide the input, but not the autofilled data?

```
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-container-inline hs_total_donor_percent_change field hs-form-field total-field">            
    <label for="one">Total Donors Percent Change *</label>    
    <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change"
           class="form-text hs-input"
           name="total_donor_percent_change"
           readonly="readonly"
           size="60"
           maxlength="128"
           type="text"
           value=""
           placeholder="0">
</div>
```

Comment: How about a hidden input field? `<input type="hidden" />` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a hidden input field:

```
<input id="inputOne" type="text"></input>
<input id="inputTwo" type="text"></input>
<input id="inputThree" type="hidden" value=""></input>
```

Then using jQuery you can set the value of the hidden input at whatever appropriate point you like:

```
$('#inputThree').val("insert value here");
```

The hidden input is pretty self explanatory, the element will be invisible but you can use the `value` attribute for data persistence.

**Edit**: It is worth noting that users can simply view the source of the webpage and will be able to see the value held in the element's `value` attribute.

Comment: I will try this in a moment, in reference to your edit, we work with clients who wouldn't know how to do that. We ran an AB test with the field disabled and it took one up to 30 seconds of clicking to realize it wasn't editable so we're choosing to hide it altogether haha

Comment: Sorry it took so long, I kept getting pulled into different projects. I just had to remove my `<label>`s text and this worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think a `disabled` attribute can help you in this. Can you try with the following code?

```
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-container-inline hs_total_donor_percent_change field hs-form-field total-field">            
    <label for="one">Total Donors Percent Change *</label>    
    <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change"
           class="form-text hs-input"
           name="total_donor_percent_change"
           readonly="readonly"
           size="60"
           maxlength="128"
           type="text"
           value=""
           placeholder="0"
           disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Can you try with this jquery code? This code will prevent typing anything into text field.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change').bind("paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried the disabled field and it returns NaN since the JS doesn't update it.

Comment: @user4875251, I modified my previous answer. Can you try with the jquery code I provide?